# Problems configuring a Memcached/Couchbase on Windows 8.1 x64

Tags: memcached, windows-8.1, couchbase

I'm having trouble starting a Couchbase 2.5.1 enterprise edition server process with Memcached buckets. I get a permanent "server down" message when I navigate to:

```
http://localhost:8091/index.html
```

The server logs just give this error for all the buckets I create.

```
[error_logger:error,2014-09-02T11:45:58.320,ns_1@127.0.0.1:error_logger<0.6.0>:ale_error_logger_handler:log_msg:119]** Generic server <0.2989.5> terminating 
** Last message in was {'$gen_cast',
                           {connect_done,4,
                               {error,couldnt_connect_to_memcached}}}
** When Server state == {state,4,0,0,
                               {[{{stats,<<>>},
                                  {<0.2341.0>,#Ref<0.0.8.143607>},
                                  {1409,638548,233000},
                                  2}],
                                []},
                               {[],[]},
                               {[],[]},
                               connecting,undefined,"Customer",
                               still_connecting,undefined,[]}
** Reason for termination == 
** {bad_return_value,{stop,{error,couldnt_connect_to_memcached}}}
```

I'm running Windows 8.1 x64 and Couchbase 2.5.1. What's odd is that on another machine with the same setup, I can run Couchbase just fine. After searching on the Internet for a while, I found this link: http://irwinj.blogspot.in/2013/03/installing-couchbase-on-windows-8.html, but that's for Win8 + Couchbase 2. The referenced bug link says the issue has been fixed. So, I'm not sure what to do next next.

Any pointers would be great.

Thanks!

ps: If this question belongs to a different stack-exchange website, please let me know, I'll migrate the question there.

Comment: At this point you should answer your own question. Or delete it.